# Regex to get the text after first "space"?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, extract, space

Here a string I need to parse using regex.

> *http://carto1.wallonie.be/documents/terrils/fiche_terril.idc?TERRIL_id=1 Crachet 7/12*

In fact this is an url followed by 1 space and a text.
I need to extract url and the text in 2 separate ways.

To extract the url `\S+` is working just fine.

But to extract the text after first space, it gets really hard to understand.

I am using [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=a732be6cf2b7cb92cec5f9ee6ebca756). (I don't know if [this link to edit the code](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit?_id=a732be6cf2b7cb92cec5f9ee6ebca756) will work)

EDIT:

Using (\S+) (.+) gives me something weird:
[image]

Comment: Please always specify the language or tool you intend to use. [Regex implementations vary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html), and a solution that works in one language may not work in another.

Comment: Thanks. Added in first post with link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Pipes documentation](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=operators#Regex), it looks like it uses fairly standard regex syntax. Try this:

```
^(\S+)\s(.+)$
```

Then the URL will be $1 and the comment will be $2. The `.` operator matches any character, which you will need since it looks like the comments may have spaces.

EDIT: changed from literal space to `\s` since you might be looking at some odd whitespace character(s). You might as well throw a `^` and `$` in there too, so the match fails instead of doing something weird.

Comment: May want to add a `^` perhaps?

Comment: The `^` may be nice for human readability, but it is not necessary. Since the `+` operators are greedy, they will both grab as many characters as possible, which in this case will necessarily be the entire string.

Comment: I think there are hidden characters as, replacing \S by "X" gives me: xtr&gt; http://carto1.wallonie.be/documents/terrils/fiche_terril.idc?TERRIL_id=1 Crachet 7/12

Comment: Interesting. Yeah what looks like a space might actually be something slightly more complex. Safer to use `\s`.

Comment: In fact, the first space is not a space but something else! Replacing \s by "X" highlight only the second space. I tried every expression, but cannot highlight what is the first space. Maybe that's an other question and I should create something new?

Comment: Ah, I get what you're saying now. If \s can't pick it up, then you might have to take a different approach. Try calling it out as "not any possible URL character" like so: `[^0-9a-zA-Z:;?&%=@#|~/\\$\-_.+!*'(),]`